# IEnumerable of Options to Option of IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq, monads, option-type

I have a 3rd party method that get IEnumerable of T and evaluates it.
I would like to introduce [Option with exceptional values](https://github.com/nlkl/Optional)(either) in my LINQ evaluation statements(select, where...) for the value that needs to get fed into the method.

For each T element I would like to have a method that can return the transformed element or an error (leaving it as [deferred execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/deferred-execution-example)) and If error is returned evaluation should stop there. (technically this can be achieved with throwing an exception, but this is exactly what im trying to avoid using Option)

I was wondering if this concept can be achieved with LINQ or more generally in C#?

If it can't be implemented this leads me to replace completely option in my code with throwing exceptions, because the same problem could show up for the client using my API with Options.

In summary this is what i am trying to achieve:

This could be one possible mothod signture to implement:

```
public Option<IEnumerable<T>,TError> Sequence<T,TError>(IEnumerable<Option<T,TError>> options)
```

Which:

- Should leave IEnumerable of T with deferred execution
- Should return first error found
- Should stop when error found

** Final method needs IEnumerable of T which will eval it (it could be 3rd party method that i cannot access)
   and I don't want to evaluate the IEnumerable twice

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, I don't think what you're asking for is possible if you are just given `IEnumerable<Option<T>>`. When returning or yielding from the generator, you'd have to decide immediately whether to return a "None" type, in the case that somethings wrong with one of your `Option<T>`. That means evaulating each element of the input in the worst (and probably most common case), where there is no "None" among your `Option<T>`s.

Comment: Is there an alternative way to handle errors of the IEnumerable elements in the code without throwing exception(including the points above)?

Comment: If you're looking to determine up-front whether you have an "error" element in your `IEnumerable`, then either way, you're going to have to keep looking at elements until you find one. Throwing an exception or just checking explicitly for a None/`null` state (in whatever would have consumed that function you write above) amounts to roughly the same solution.

Comment: Yes but with exceptions you can stop the execution while with options you cant (you can but than you have to have control on the top most executing function which sometimes you dont have access to)

Comment: That's true. You'll have to decide what works best for your purposes. For your question though, I only mean to point out there really can't be anything in LINQ or C# to save you here, and you'll instead have to take a different approach or change your requirements.

Comment: @CountOren - Can you post the `Option<T>` class or is it from some library?

Comment: I think you really want a public `Task<IEnumerable<T>> Sequence(IEnumerable<Option<T, TException>>)`.  The problem with returning an Option is that it doesn't know whether it has Some or None until it does some work.  `Task<T>` does some work and then has a Value or an Exception.

Comment: @Enigmativity yes it is - https://github.com/nlkl/Optional

Comment: @DavidB do you have an example?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to return from this method - do you want a sequence of all the values that didn't error along with the first error that might have been thrown?

Comment: No, I need the error message too. I am searching a way to be able to mimic the behavior of throwing an exception with errors as return type. The point here that I don't think it is possible to be able to mimic this behavior without access to the function that handles the execution, or in other words I cannot leave some kind of IEnumerable that 3rd party function will consume that will stop when there is an error and make in some point of the execution chain to be able to return the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying for a while to solve this problem, and having the feeling that exceptions should be able to be mimic with either monads, I posted a [more conceptual version of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44665959/replacing-exceptions-with-either-maybe-option?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Thanks, and based on mark's answer which as well confirmed my suspicion about "Either being isomorphic to C#/Java-style exceptions".

I was able to create the following implementation:

```
public static class LinqEitherExtension
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> UntilException<T,TException>(
        this IEnumerable<Option<T,TException>> enumerable, 
        Action<TException> errorHandler
        )
    {
        return enumerable
            .TakeWhile(e =>
                           {
                               e.MatchNone(errorHandler);
                               return e.HasValue;
                           })
            .SelectMany(e => e.ToEnumerable());
    }
}


public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var numbers = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        ThirdPartyFunction(numbers.Select(CheckNumbers).UntilException(Console.WriteLine));
        //returns: 
        //1     
        //2
        //3 is exceptional number.
    }

    public static Option<int,string> CheckNumbers(int number)
    {
        return number == 3
            ? Option.None<int, string>("3 is exceptional number.")
            : number.Some<int, string>();
    }

    //Cannot be accessed/altered
    public static void ThirdPartyFunction(IEnumerable<int> numbers)
    {
        foreach (var number in numbers) Console.WriteLine(number.ToString());
    }

}
```

Note: If the ThirdPartyFunction will continue to to do side effects (like Console.WriteLine) after consuming the enumerable, This will still leave a gap between exception throwing and using error as return type:

- Throwing exceptions approach: Will not execute any more side effects as well.
- Eithers approach : Will let the ThirdPartyFunction to finish the execution, Client consuming the output of the function can ignore the return value, But any side effect happens inside will still execute.

For what I am after this will get the job done.